# Catching unhandled exceptions decision

Tags: vb.net, unhandled-exception

I decided to turn on the strict option on one of my applications. And for the life of me I couldn't figure out how to make a small bit of code compile. In a module I had this bit of code

```
    Sub Main()
        AddHandler AppDomain.CurrentDomain.UnhandledException, AddressOf CurrentDomain_UnhandledException
    End Sub
    Private Sub CurrentDomain_UnhandledException(sender As Object, e As UnhandledExceptionEventArgs)
        e.ExitApplication = False
    End Sub
```

after looking around and seeing another post about putting it in the ApplicationEvents I got it to work by handling said event. So out curiosity I decided to move the AddHandler and into the same class and then it became clear that its the same class name but different namespaces:

```
Partial Friend Class MyApplication
    Private Sub MyApplication_UnhandledException(sender As Object, e As UnhandledExceptionEventArgs) Handles Me.UnhandledException
        e.ExitApplication = False
        AddHandler AppDomain.CurrentDomain.UnhandledException, AddressOf CurrentDomain_UnhandledException
    End Sub

    Private Sub CurrentDomain_UnhandledException(sender As Object, e As System.UnhandledExceptionEventArgs)
        e.ExitApplication = False
    End Sub
End Class
```

Here is a link to both:

- [Microsoft.VisualBasic.ApplicationServices.UnhandledExceptionEventArgs](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.visualbasic.applicationservices.unhandledexceptioneventargs%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)
- [System.UnhandledExceptionEventArgs](https://msdn.microsoft.com/query/dev14.query?appId=Dev14IDEF1&l=EN-US&k=k%28System.UnhandledExceptionEventArgs%29;k%28TargetFrameworkMoniker-.NETFramework)

So my question is, which one should I use? I'm wanting to prevent the app from shutting down... but both options seem like what I want.

Comment: In your second code block, I don't think you want the `AddHandler` within the `MyApplication_UnhandledException` function - that doesn't make much sense.  It might work since I believe that (VB) handler will be called first, and the `CurrentDomain.UnhandledException` handler second, but it doesn't make much sense.

Comment: Setting e.ExitApplication to False accomplishes nothing.  That stopped working 11 years ago, don't bother.

Comment: @StuartWhitehouse You may have missed that the problem reared its head when I turned on strict. Up till today this code has been happily working for over 3 years. Honestly i'm surprised it did work now. The code I posted above very clearly shows the compiler error and is not intended to show what I have had in my code base this entire time... I'm not angry or anything (despite how this reads) it's just that both here and in the answer it was mentioned that the code I'm showing does work. :D I know, the compiler told me too

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `System.UnhandledException` doesn't have an `ExitApplication` member (see the docs you linked), so cannot be used to stop the application exiting - once this is called the application will always terminate.  Generally the `Microsoft.VisualBasic` namespace are helpers for VB that more-or-less duplicate functionality available elsewhere.  The closest equivalent to the VisualBasic handler that you mention is instead the `Application.ThreadException` one.  This and the `AppDomain.CurrentDomain.UnhandledException` are both described quite well in the [MS docs](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.application.threadexception%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).

To prevent the app from shutting either the `VisualBasic` one or the `ThreadException` one can be used.  I've used the `Microsoft.VisualBasic` one in the past to achieve something similar to what you are doing.

Comment: yeah, I know that `System.UnhandledExceptionEventArgs` doesn't contain `ExitApplication` The code that I moved over to ApplicationEvents was just AddHandler, when I told VisualStudio to add the Sub for me it prepended `System.` and that is when I noticed the two distinct versions of UnhandledExceptionEventArgs. Goes to show the problem with copy pasting code without knowing what it does :D